# any simple library to analye the xml like strings( not standard xml) in java language

Tags: java, xml, eclipse

I want to write a function in java to meet such requirement. 
provide a string like the following contains special xml tags.

```
defaultcolor contents
sdfsafsadfas
sdfsfsadfasfsa
safdsafasf<red>redconents</red><blue>bluecontents
blueconents continues....
</blue>safasf
<yellow>yellow contents</yellow>safdsafd'
```

I need to extract   each string part in sequence and related tag, there will be another program to draw these string in different color into a special eclipse console. (or anyone can suggest doing such requirement in a better way? )

I need an xml like parser to easily parse the string (the string is not an valid/standard xml string).

the method siganature is like the following,

```
public List<coloredString>  getColoredStringList(String source);
```

the returned value should be an List for the following type:

```
class ColoredString{
 private ColorType color;
 private String contents;
 //getter and setters...

 }

enum ColorType{
  DEFAULT,RED,BLUE,YELLOW;
}
```

i tried to write a parser (just use common java), i didn't write a parse for a long time (only did that at school:) ),  anyone know a easier way to write a parse in java (using some existing lib....)

Comment: What would be the output you expect? What have you tried already?

Answer (score 0):

As i understand, you want to use most of the data from this file.

If its valid XML, you can use JAXB/Castor frameworks to convert XML to Custom Java Class objects. Then these objects can be used to read XML data.

XSLTs can be used to convert from one XML to another XML format.

If its not valid XML, then you need to make your own String parser. Then inside that parser you can identify sections of String which are XML and accordingly process that XML using XML to object libraries as defined above.

Answer (score 0):

You might have some luck with an SGML parser, SGML is a markup similar to XML but is much more relaxed.